# Pass Custom Data from Page Template to WooCommerce Cart Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am capturing some data on **page template**, Now I want to pass that data on cart page how can i do that??

I found some tutorials but they are telling pass custom data from product page, But I want to pass from **page template**.

[image]

In the above image you can see, I have 5 layers(Support Layer, Comfort Layer, Dimension, Fabric, Final Look) in every layer I am capturing some data like material, size, thickness etc now I want to pass this data in cart with total price.

below some links i found

https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-data-woocommerce-order/
https://sarkware.com/adding-custom-product-fields-to-woocommerce-without-using-plugins/

Please help me.

Comment: Please share the code you have developed so far. Why does it have to be a page template? Why aren't you using a product page? Why aren't you using the product shortcode if you need to display a product on a page. Have you considered [Product Addons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/)?

Comment: Thank you for reply. see updated question I have created Page template just because of specific requirement as you can see my image is tabbed panel once you entered data in first layer then you can go in next and so on

Comment: That's better. But you can create a custom product template, then you'd be able to follow the posted tutorials exactly

Comment: Can you please suggest something how to create custom product template..

Comment: @helgatheviking you have any idea please suggest me  I'm struggling..